# Tensorflow GPU is not identifying my GPUs

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia, cudnn

I have been trying to use Tensorflow GPU, but apparently, Tersorflow is not identifying my GPUs.

When I run:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

As an output, only my CPU shows up. I have checked all of the versions of everything and they seem to be compatible. I have CUDA 10.1 with CUDA Toolkit, cuDNN 7.5 and Tensorflow 1.13.1. I am running everything on Ubuntu 18.xx

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you actually have a CUDA compatible GPU?

Comment: Yes. I have a NVIDIA GM200 (GeForce GTX Titan X). The computing capability is also above the one required by Tensorflow

Comment: What is the output of `nvidia-smi`?

Comment: This is the output:
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.43       Driver Version: 418.43       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 17%   56C    P0    62W / 250W |      0MiB / 12210MiB |      0%      Default |

Answer (score 0):

what is the output of:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

On my system, `tensorflow` is not recognizing **GPU** because it is a **XLA_GPU**. I'm not really sure why a `XLA_GPU` is not also a `GPU`, seems there is a OR statement missing somewhere in the tensorflow-gpu code.

If above code does not list any GPUs (and you have one):

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

… worked for me.