# It seems tensorflow is not recognizing my GPU, how to fix it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I installed `tensorflow-gpu`into my new computer, and the system, and everything is recognizing perfectly my GPU, for that I tried on my terminal:

## Nvidia test:

```
nvcc  --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

However, trying to know if tensorflow recognizes the GPU I tried:

## Tensorflow test:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
```

## Result:

```
2020-05-04 22:51:25.687188: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-04 22:51:25.687914: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:06:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.65GHz coreCount: 34 deviceMemorySize: 7.79GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2020-05-04 22:51:25.687956: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-05-04 22:51:25.687972: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-05-04 22:51:25.687986: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-05-04 22:51:25.688002: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-05-04 22:51:25.688015: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-05-04 22:51:25.688029: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-05-04 22:51:25.688112: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.7'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-05-04 22:51:25.688124: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1598] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2020-05-04 22:51:25.688160: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-05-04 22:51:25.688170: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]      0 
2020-05-04 22:51:25.688178: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 0:   N 
False
```

On the other hand, following the suggestion given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55098742/tensorflow-gpu-is-not-identifying-my-gpus). I tried the following commands:

## Other Tensorflow test:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

And I get the following logs.

## My logs:

```
2020-05-04 22:53:35.486634: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-04 22:53:35.487357: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:06:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.65GHz coreCount: 34 deviceMemorySize: 7.79GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2020-05-04 22:53:35.487403: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-05-04 22:53:35.487421: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-05-04 22:53:35.487436: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-05-04 22:53:35.487451: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-05-04 22:53:35.487464: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-05-04 22:53:35.487477: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-05-04 22:53:35.487564: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.7'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-05-04 22:53:35.487574: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1598] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2020-05-04 22:53:35.487591: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-05-04 22:53:35.487598: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]      0 
2020-05-04 22:53:35.487604: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 0:   N 
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 12034437465466050746
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 16469163198093824972
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 5712734079173508475
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
]
```

is tensorflow recognizing my GPU? Some results tell me True and other False. Please help.

## Edit

Other test I have done:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()
True
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Your GPU is being detected, you just didn't install everything correctly. You need this post: [Which TensorFlow and CUDA version combinations are compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622525/which-tensorflow-and-cuda-version-combinations-are-compatible). I think your `cuda` is OK, but `cudnn` isn't installed correctly, as from the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow is detecting your GPU but it does not means that it is **fully** functional.

As you can see in te logs, the `libcuddn` lib. does not appears to be installed on the system.

You can find the installation instructions of this library in the official documentation : https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html

Make sure that you also have all the dependancies listed there installed : https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu